# Element wise addition in spark rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD of RDD[Array[Array[Double]]]. So essentially each element is a matrix. I need to do element wise addition.

so if the first element of the rdd is

```
    1 2
    3 4
```

and second element is

```
   5 6
   7 8
```

at the end i need to have

```
   6 8
   10 12
```

I have looked into zip but not sure if I can use it for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use zip, but you'll have to use it twice, once for the rows and once for the columns:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(List(Array(Array(1.0,2.0),Array(3.0,4.0)), 
                              Array(Array(5.0,6.0),Array(7.0,8.0))))

rdd.reduce((a,b) => a.zip(b).map {case (c,d) => c.zip(d).map{ case (x,y) => x+y}})
```

Comment: This method works for `RDD[Array[Array[Double]]]`, but not `RDD[RDD[Array[Double]]]` (see [SPARK-5063](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5063)). I think I have a similar problem with OP. Basically, I need to substract/add two distributed matrices, such as RowMatrix. However, because of the size of the matrics is huge, they can't be collected.